# Tricks for searching on msdn

Tags: search, msdn

**Foreword** 
Before asking a question that probably will pretend to downvoting (as it seems to me) I remebered an answer on 
 [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99182/answer-deleted-because-it-came-from-msdn)

> I like getting MSDN links as answers because MSDN is so hard to navigate, it's one of the worst sites to find something in.

**Question** 
Suppose I'm new to some subject. But I know what I'm searching for and this could be some symbol operator (`+`,`-`, etc). Seems easy. Then how to find an article describing some directive like `@` (for asp.net)? I'm aware of what it is. Besides I'd been trying to search `code blocks`, `rendering` etc. And I was typing `asp.net` every time. As a result I met some articles close to my question but not similar. So are there some tricks for a searching string on `MSDN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pro trick for searching on MSDN is never to use the MSDN site search. **Always use Google.**

I can usually find exactly what I'm looking for on MSDN by typing in the name of the concept/type/etc. because it's either the first or second result on Google.

Failing that, you can always use Google Site Search and explicitly instruct it to search the MSDN library. To do that, use this form of search query:

```
"your search term(s)" site:msdn.microsoft.com
```

I never understood that comment on Meta. I can count on one hand the number of times I've had trouble finding something on MSDN, and I'm a Microsoft-stack programmer with a terrible memory. I use the site all that time. I might be able to give more specific advice if you gave a specific example.

Comment: I use google. Always. And it seems strange that such site as MSDN doesn't have convenient serch tools.